# tableView(_:viewforHeaderInSection:) Not Being Called

Tags: ios, uitableview

This one is driving me crazy.

1. I have a view controller, subclass of `UITableViewController`.
2. The table view's data source is replaced by a custom data source object, other than the view controller (by default, `UITableViewController` is both the delgate and the data source of its table view).
3. The custom data source does NOT implement `tableView(_:titleForHeaderInSection:)`
4. The view controller (the delegate) implements:

   - `tableView(_:viewforHeaderInSection:)`
   - `tableView(_:heightForHeaderInSection:)`
   - `tableView(_:estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection)`

   **...neither of which is ever called.**

As a result, my table view sections do not display any header.

If I specify the table view's **global** section header height:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 12 // (say)
```

...then blank headers are displayed, but `tableView(_:titleForHeaderInSection:)` et al **are still not called** and my custom header views never get displayed.

Similar questions have been asked before, and Apple's docs seems to not be 100% correct, however I am positive that I am doing everything that is required (I have tried all configurations).

**What am I missing?**

The codebase is large, and not mine; perhaps I am missing something somwehere but don't know what else to look for...

---

**Update**

I created a new, minimal project to test and it turns out I only need to implement these two delegate methods (and not modify any properties of the table view):

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)) // (say)
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red // (say)
    return view
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 10.0 // (say)
}
```

...to have my custom section header view displayed.

**However,** the same setup does not work on my existing project. Something, somewhere must be interfering...

---

**Update 2**

I sublcassed `UITableView` to see what was going on, but still can't figure it out (see inline comments):

import UIKit

```
class DebugTableView: UITableView {

    // GETS EXECUTED:
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder) 
    }

    override var estimatedSectionHeaderHeight: CGFloat {
        // NEVER GETS EXECUTED:
        get { 
            return super.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight
        }
        // NEVER GETS EXECUTED:
        set (newValue) { 
            super.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = newValue
        }
    }

    override var sectionHeaderHeight: CGFloat {
        // NEVER GETS EXECUTED:
        get { 
            return super.sectionHeaderHeight
        }
        // NEVER GETS EXECUTED:
        set (newValue) { 
            super.sectionHeaderHeight = newValue
        }
    }

    // NEVER GETS EXECUTED:
    override func headerView(forSection section: Int) -> UITableViewHeaderFooterView? {
        let view = super.headerView(forSection: section)
        return view
    }

    // GETS EXECUTED ONCE PER CELL:            
    override func rectForHeader(inSection section: Int) -> CGRect {
        var rect = super.rectForHeader(inSection: section)
        rect.size.height = 1000 // HAS NO EFFECT
        return rect
    }
}
```

Comment: show all your tableview's delegate methods also show numberofsection and numberofrows also

Comment: My table has only one section. Number of rows is non-zero, and my table displays its data without problems. I made numberOfSections to return 2 (effectively, displaying each cell twice) just in case, to no avail.

Comment: Did set this tableView.delegate = self

Comment: The **delegate** methods my view controller currently implementsa re: `heightForRowAt` (returns >0), `heightForHeaderInSection` (returns > 0), `viewForHeaderInSection` (returns non-nil), `willDisplay`, and `didSelectRowAt`.

Comment: The delgate **is** set by default (it is a `UITableViewController` subclass) and not unset anywhere. Other delegate methods **are called**.

Comment: Remove this and check once tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

It turns out there was an auxiliary object **overtaking the role of table view delegate and hiding it.**

This class:

- Adopts the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol and implements **most** of its methods (but **not** the header/footer-related ones),
- Sets itself as the table view's delegate inside the table view controller's `viewDidAppear()` method,
- Keeps a reference to the table view controller,
- When it's implementation of (say) tableView(_:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:) is called, it in turn calls the table view controller's equivalent method, giving the impression that the view controller is still the delegate:

  ```
  class ManInTheMiddle: NSObject, UITableViewDelegate {
      var formerDelegate: UITableViewController?

      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
          formerDelegate?.tableView(tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
          // Do some other stuff...
      }
  }
  ```

This is why **some** methods of `UITableViewDelegate` where being called on my table view controller and some weren't.

I discovered this by overriding the table view's `delegate` property:

```
class DebugTableView: UITableView {

    // ...
    override var delegate: UITableViewDelegate? {
        get {
            return super.delegate
        }
        set (newValue) {
            super.delegate = newValue // < BREAKPOINT HERE
        }
    }
```

...out of desperation (there was no strong reason to suspect the delegate was swapped, being that *most* methods worked...)

<rant>Damn, do I **hate** these kind of dirty hacks... This is almost `#define true false` territory, sheesh... 
</rant>

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set `sectionHeaderHeight` also, not only estimated height!

like,

> Swift 4.0

```
    tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 25
```

and then just override `viewForHeaderInSection`. and no need to override any other delegates!

Comment: The sample project I created to test does **neither** of this things, and still `viewForHeaderInSection` **is** called.

Comment: Setting those two causes empty headers of the specified height to be displayed, but `viewForHeaderInSection` is **still not called**.

Comment: then implement `heightForHeaderInSection` also and return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` from it.

Comment: `heightForHeaderInSection:` isn't called either!

Comment: It is hard to get idea without seeing your all implementation! upload one demo project if you can!

Comment: That is the problem: The demo project **works** (see update to my question). But in my actual project, no matter what I do, neither `heightForHeaderInSection:` nor `viewForHeaderInSection` are ever called.

Comment: I have searched project-wide, and nobody else seems to be interfering with my table view. Unless there's something to look for that I'm not aware.

Comment: have you check that your other delegates getting called by putting breakpoint ?

Comment: **Yes;** all delegate methods **except** `tableView(_:viewforHeaderInSection:)`, `tableView(_:heightForHeaderInSection:)` and `tableView(_:estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection)` are called (same for footers).

Comment: once try to remove `estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection`, and remove estimate heignh from viewdidload also. and implement only two delegate `viewforHeaderInSection` and `heightForHeaderInSection` and return static height from it!

Comment: I found the problem (see my answer above); Thank you for your help and feedback.